# XML to coldfusion and mysql

Tags: xml, coldfusion

sorry for putting such a vague question, i was rushing to get to work, my fault, apologies.

Here is the full question.

I have an xml file which is 7mb in size and i would like to extract the info and add it to mysql and create new tables with the extracted info.

Below is the structure of the xml file (the original file has over 1185 properties), this example only has one.

I would like to know how i could remove elements that are not required from the feed with coldfusion and then import the required fields into tables in mysql

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root>
 <properties>
 <property>
 <details>
    <propertyid>112</propertyid>
    <name>Spain, Costa del Sol, Marbella, Capanes del Golf Apartment- 5* hotel facilities</name>
    <reference>2360</reference>
    <price>376242</price>
    <pricetype id="4">N/A</pricetype>
    <status id="3">For Sale</status>
    <description>
        <p>Capanes del Golf is one of the most exclusive project in Costa del Sol at this time. The complex with luxurious apartments is located near the road to Benahavis and just a few minutes away from the coast.</p>
        <p>Positioned at the very heart of the New Marbella Club Golf Course (El Higueral Golf), its location is unique as it is totally surrounded by the course. As well as its stunning location at the heart of the course, the complex also enjoys more than 50.000 m2 of carefully landscaped Mediterranean gardens with water areas, swimmingpools as well as a private Club Social with Spa and fitness.</p>
        <p>All of the apartments at Capanes del Golf have a golf share to the New Marbella Club Golf Course included in the sales price, this allows the client full access to the golf course surrounding the project. Capanes del Golf is a project not just to be lived but also enjoyed as a home.</p>
        <p>
            <strong>Additional Features</strong>
        </p>
        <p>5 * Hotel facilties<br />Gym<br />Health spa available on site<br />Established on a Golf resort</p>
    </description>
    <levels>0</levels>
    <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>
    <bathrooms>1</bathrooms>
    <areacovered>189</areacovered>
    <areaplot>0</areaplot>
    <areaveranda>0</areaveranda>
    <areagarden>0</areagarden>
    <promote>0</promote>
    <sleeps>0</sleeps>
    <deliverydate />
    <googlemapurl />
    <latitude />
    <longitude />
    <mapzoom />
    <mapactive>0</mapactive>
    <investment />
    <ownernotes />
    <dateadded />
    <dateupdated>01/01/2013</dateupdated>
    <sortweight>0</sortweight>
    <urlalias>spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities-1</urlalias>
    <url>http://127.0.0.1/properties-for-sale/spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities-1</url>
</details>
<location>
    <country id="27" urlalias="spain">Spain</country>
    <district id="52" urlalias="costa-del-sol">Costa del Sol</district>
    <location id="929" urlalias="marbella">Marbella</location>
</location>
<types>
    <type id="8" urlalias="apartment-flat">Apartment-Flat</type>
</types>
<categories />
<features />
<images>
    <imageurl>http://127.0.0.1/media/property-images/spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities_full_11.jpg</imageurl>
    <imageurl>http://127.0.0.1/media/property-images/spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities_full_12.jpg</imageurl>
    <imageurl>http://127.0.0.1/media/property-images/spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities_full_13.jpg</imageurl>
    <imageurl>http://127.0.0.1/media/property-images/spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities_full_14.jpg</imageurl>
    <imageurl>http://127.0.0.1/media/property-images/spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities_full_15.jpg</imageurl>
    <imageurl>http://127.0.0.1/media/property-images/spain-costa-del-sol-marbella-hotel-facilities_full_16.jpg</imageurl>
</images>
 </property>
 </properties>
 </root>
```

Im also trying to output the data into JSON format using coldfusion im using the code by Raymond Camden below:

```
 <cfset cachedJSON = cacheGet("jsonstr")>
 <cfif isNull(cachedJSON)>

 <cfset xmlFile = expandPath("./xml/poj.xml")>
 <cfset xmlData = xmlParse(xmlFile)>

 <cfscript>
 function xmlToStruct(xml x) {
 var s = {};

 if(xmlGetNodeType(x) == "DOCUMENT_NODE") {
 s[structKeyList(x)] = xmlToStruct(x[structKeyList(x)]);
 }

 if(structKeyExists(x, "xmlAttributes") && !structIsEmpty(x.xmlAttributes)) {
 s.attributes = {};
 for(var item in x.xmlAttributes) {
 s.attributes[item] = x.xmlAttributes[item];
 }
 }

 if(structKeyExists(x, "xmlChildren")) {
 for(var i=1; i<=arrayLen(x.xmlChildren); i++) {
 if(structKeyExists(s, x.xmlchildren[i].xmlname)) {
 if(!isArray(s[x.xmlChildren[i].xmlname])) {
 var temp = s[x.xmlchildren[i].xmlname];
 s[x.xmlchildren[i].xmlname] = [temp];
 }
 arrayAppend(s[x.xmlchildren[i].xmlname], xmlToStruct(x.xmlChildren[i]));
 } else {
 s[x.xmlChildren[i].xmlName] = xmlToStruct(x.xmlChildren[i]);
 }
 }
 }

 return s;
 }

 cachedJSON = serializeJSON(xmlToStruct(xmlData));

 </cfscript>

 <cfset cachePut("jsonstr", cachedJSON)>

 </cfif>

 <cfcontent reset="true" type="application/json"><cfoutput>#cachedJSON#</cfoutput>
```

Basically this will be for a real estate website which is getting an xml feed generated by a wordpress system. The data is outputting ok using a jquery function to parse the xml and also using the coldfusion serializeJSON function. I am getting confused by the nodes in the structure of the xml as what i would really like to do is add it all to tables in mysql and run an update once a day to update the properties in the database. My coldfusion and java knowledge is not exactly the greatest so please forgive me if i am making things difficult here. The reason i want to store everything in the database is so that i can have the country/region/city/town tables, currency table, property type table etc so that i can build a search function from those fields.

Im trying to import the xml into mysql using the navicat import feature, but that is not working out the way i need it to as alot of the info is in the  tag. I hope i making sense here, i mean is there even a need to store all this info into a database and just display the properties straight from the feed?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? So we can help you with specific problem.

Comment: I am holding off voting to close this question in case the person acts on the advice in my "answer", thus making this question viable.

Comment: Sorry i will add everything in a few minutes im sorry for being so vague i didnt hvae time to post full question as i was rushed.

Comment: About being rushed, remember that it takes less time to do something well than it does to do it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate any effort on your part to *find out* how to do this with CFML, so I'm going to be as superficial with this answer as you've suggested your own research has been.

ColdFusion has a bunch of support for XML interrogation and manipulating. Start here: "[Using XML and WDDX](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+XML+and+WDDX)". Ignore the stuff specifically about WDDX, but read, experiment with, and understand all the XML possibilities. Pay specific attention to these functions: [`xmlSearch()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/XmlSearch), [`xmlTransform()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/XmlTransform). Also the section entitled "[Modifying a ColdFusion XML object](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/XmlTransform)".

For what you're asking, a suggestion to read the docs and act on those is probably an appropriate level of help.

If you do that, and then *try something* and still have problems: post the code - or a pared down repro case that *just* demonstrates the problem (read this: "[Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html)", and the docs I link to within it) - and then ask a more directed question.

I don't know how better to answer your question as you don't indicate how far along this process you are, so don't know where I'd be wasting my time offering advice on something you perhaps already have tried / understand / etc. I don't want to waste either of our time (although I'm more concerned about my own time wastage, I'll admit that).